# Por quê meu cartao SD corrompe no salvamento do arduino?

Tags: c, c++, memória, arduino, txt

Tenho um cartão micro SD 4GB da Kingston e um código datalogger que exclui o arquivo exitente e cria um novo com os novos valores das variáveis. Segue abaixo o código:

```
void back_var() {

  SD.remove("/backup/BACKUP.txt");
  char var_up[] = "%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;";
  sprintf(
    variaveis,        //Nome da String a ser criada
    var_up,           //Char utilizado para armazenar a String
    valor1,    //Informações
    valor2,
    valor3,
    valor4,
    valor5,
    valor6,
    valor7,
    valor8,
    valor9,
    valor10,
    valor11,
    valor11,
    valor12,
    valor13,
    valor14,
    valor15
  );
  Serial.println("Print das variáveis:");
  Serial.println(variaveis);
  Serial.println(botoeira_entrada_S15);
  SD.begin (4);
  backup = SD.open("/backup/BACKUP.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (backup) {
    Serial.println("Inserindo variáveis no SD...");
    backup.print(variaveis);
    backup.print('|');
    Serial.println("Variáveis inseridas no SD!");
    backup.close();



  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Erro ao abrir arquivo de Update");
  }
}
```

O problema é que depois de determinado tempo o arquivo txt é corrompido e criam-se outros arquivos ilegíveis.
Por quê isso ocorre? E como resolver?
Segue abaixo os arquivos ilegíveis criados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já testou o código com outros cartões? Qual o resultado?

Comment: ainda não testei com outro cartão @AugustoVasques, você acha que pode ser o cartão?

Comment: Teste outros cartões e **SE POSSÍVEL**, não quero ser acusado de sumir com seus dados, formate(formatação completa) esse seu SD 4GB da Kingston.

Comment: Acredito que o erro possa estar neste seu `SD.begin(4)`, você deve chama-lo somente no **setup()**. Outra coisa, você deve testar se foi possível inicializar o cartão da seguinte forma: `if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("Falha na inicialização!");
    while (1);
  }`

Comment: editei meu código com a foto dos arquivos ilegíveis que são criados @AugustoVasques

Comment: @EsdrasXavier o teste para verificar a inicialização do cartão é feita... editei meu código com a imagem de arquivos criados dentro do cartão

Comment: @EsdrasXavier, não é possível chama-lo somente no setup() pois também é utilizada a comunicação com a internet... tem outra forma?

Comment: No código que você compartilhou você não faz a verificacao  se o mesmo foi inicializado corretamente, você somente verifica se for aberto ou não. Para verificar a inicialização deve -se utilizar `if (!SD.begin(4)) Serial.println("Falha na inicialização!");`.  Outra coisa na parte de cima possui um `SD.remove()`, antes mesmo do **SD.begin()**.

Comment: @SarahTavares O que você quer dizer com,  _também é utilizada a comunicação com a internet._ ?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier enviamos os dados pelo SPI para um banco de dados

Comment: Entendi. Neste caso então no final de sua função tente colocar um `SD.end()`, para finalizar a conexão, seria tipo um *"Remover com segurança"*

Comment: @EsdrasXavier vou tentar, obrigada! o SD.remove() está antes do SD.begin() mesmo, vou alterar aqui, obrigada! Alguma outra coisa no meu código? vou tentar novamente

Comment: Outra coisa, todas essas sua variáveis são do tipo _double_?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier a variável é int... pode ser isso?

Comment: mudei a variável para double agora @EsdrasXavier.... a variável int pode ter influencia sobre o cartao sd corrompido por alguma razão?

Comment: Neste caso você esta utilizando _sprintf_, o que eu faria seria escrever variável por variável, talvez pode ser que esta corrompendo a memoria do arduino :p, mas não garanto, faz um teste de cololocar: `backup.print(variavel); backup.print('|');  backup.print(variavel2);`, e veja se dará o mesmo problema. E podes manter o **int**

Comment: obrigada, vou fazer isso!